# Why is Diff always positive when comparing dates?

Tags: php

I'm using this code to return the number of days between two dates - today, and a date from the database:

```
$now = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime($row[$CalendarField]);
$interval = $now->diff($date2);
$age = $interval->days;
```

How can I alter the code so that `$age` returns a negative value for dates in the past?

Comment: So you want to turn `x - y` into `y - x`?

Comment: it always depends on both dates that you compare, if now is greater than the time it will be positiv, otherwise negativ? BTW You could do $date2->diff($now)

Comment: Whether `$date2` is in the past or future `$age` always comes out positive at the moment, I want it to be negative for dates in the past.

Comment: Have you checked what is in **$row[$CalendarField]** ?

Comment: Yes it'll be a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD but it could be past or future.

Comment: imo, you want to know, 1) the 'source' date compared with a 'comparison' date. Whether the 'comparison' date is before or after the source date. So, would a simple test of the two dates provide the information? i.e.  `$comparisonSign =  $comparisonDate < $sourceDate ? -1 : +1;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the **invert** property in **DateInterval** class.
http://php.net/manual/pl/class.dateinterval.php

You can also use characters **r** and **R** in **DateInterval::format** method.
http://php.net/manual/pl/dateinterval.format.php

Try to replace your code with

```
    $now = new DateTime("now");
    $date2 = new DateTime($row[$CalendarField]);
    $interval = $now->diff($date2);
    $age = $interval->format('%r%a');
```